# Execute a passed alias inside a function?

Tags: bash

**Background:**

I'm trying make a function that runs commands on a set interval because I don't have access to a "watch" program.  Simplified to it's most basic from, the function I'm trying to write is `runit() { $1; }`.

**What works:**

This works fine and dandy when I pass it things that aren't aliases.  For example, `runit "ls -l"` works fine.  I get the full output from the `ls -l` command.

**What doesn't work:**

The problem starts when I pass it an alias.  For example, setting `alias ll="ls -l"` then calling `runit "ll"` will result in `-bash: ll: command not found`.

**Things I have tried:**

When I hard-code the alias `runit() { ll; }`, it works fine and gives me what I expect.

---

I feel like I might be overlooking something, but I can't quite place my finger on it.
Why would hard-coding the alias work fine, but passing it into the function fail?
*Is there a way to accomplish what I'm attempting to do?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash function calling command given as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178604/bash-function-calling-command-given-as-argument)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `bash` man page discussion of aliases (emphases mine):

> **Aliases are expanded when a command is read**, not when it is executed. 
>   Therefore, an
>          alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take effect until the next line of input is read.   The 
>   commands
>          following  the  alias  definition on that line are not affected by the new alias.  This behavior is also an issue when functions are
>   executed.  **Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed**,  because  a  function 
>   definition  is
>          itself  a compound command.  As a consequence, aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed.
>   To
>          be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.

You can observe this effect in functions by using the type command:

```
$ run_it () { ll; }
$ type run_it
```

You should see that the body of the function contains a call to `ls -l`, not `ll`.

The last sentence of the section on aliases:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

My interpretation of that line is: if you think you want to use an alias, try writing a function first. Don't use an alias unless the function demonstrably fails to do what you need.

Comment: Looks like it might be time to change my aliases to functions.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `eval` like this:

```
$ runit() { eval $1; }
$ alias ll="ls -l"
$ runit "ll"
```

`eval` will expand any alias in `$1` before the execution.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this problem is to define a shell function rather than an alias.

```
ll () {
  ls -l "$@"
}
```

The alias is expanded as a macro on command input, whereas the shell function is matched when the command is executed. This is a perfect example of how the shell's macro processor language is good for interactive grace but rather complicates actual programming.

Comment: Why is it that this would work, but passing an alias wouldn't?