# How to write a general command logging function in Bash

Tags: bash

Here's the general command logging function I wrote:

```sh
function exec_cmd() {
  {
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$1"
    $1
  } >>./cmd.log
}
```

When I call this function with `exec_cmd "modprobe -r toa || true"`, I got an error "modprobe: FATAL: Module || not found."

Running the same command without the wrapper `exec_cmd` works as expected.

The whole script is running in strict mode. The `||` were included because only the error from this command can be ignored.

Comment: What is the need to pass || true as well?

Comment: Perhaps you need `bash -c` or `eval`.

Comment: Although in this case the error value is discarded anyway, right? Or are you running it in strict mode?

Comment: @RamanSailopal to make sure that even if toa mod is not installed, this error will be discarded

Comment: @user202729 yes, the whole script is running in strict mode which means only this command can be failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eval - Bash function calling command given as argument - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178604/bash-function-calling-command-given-as-argument)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. This question is indeed very useful. But back to the question, I would say using `$@` instead of `$1` is the key to answer the question. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the function like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
function exec_cmd() {
  {
    printf "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') %s\n" "$*"
    "$@"
  } >> ./cmd.log
}

exec_cmd modprobe -r toa || true
```

Comment: Thanks. I am also writing an almost identical answer after reading @user202729's comment. I will accept your answer since you posted the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has builtin support for printing commands as they are executed, namely the `-x` flag. From `man bash`:

> -x Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

So you can revise your script to call `set -x` as the first command, then every command after that is printed in the sequence they are called.

```sh
#!/bin/bin/env bash
set -x

modprobe -r toa || true
```

Comment: Not a bad idea for logging, but this doesn't include the date.

Comment: Of course the upside is that you don't have to remember to pass all commands to `exec_cmd`.

Comment: You can get the the date and time in the output after running `set -x` by first setting `PS4='\D{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} + '`.